# Decrypt an encrypted CSV file and save it into a byteArray

Tags: c#, csv, encryption

My code below is getting an error stating **"Length of the data to decrypt is invalid."**
when I try to copy it to MemoryStream. How can I solve this?

```
var table = (Encoding.Default.GetString(result, 0, result.Length - 1))
    .Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
MemoryStream encryptedStream = new MemoryStream();
encryptedStream.Write(result, 0, filelength);     

DESCryptoServiceProvider DES = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);
DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);
ICryptoTransform desdecrypt = DES.CreateDecryptor();          

MemoryStream decryptedStream = new MemoryStream();
encryptedStream.Position = 0;
CryptoStream decryptStream = new CryptoStream(encryptedStream, desdecrypt,
    CryptoStreamMode.Read);
decryptStream.CopyTo(decryptedStream);
decryptedStream.Position = 0;
```

Comment: Is the CSV encrypted as a whole, or are the fields encrypted? if its the whole file, first decrypt then break it down - not like you did

Comment: it is whole file encrypted

Comment: And `result` is the incoming data?

Comment: This looked like C# so I tagged it as such. If this is not correct, please add the correct language tag.

Comment: If it is whole file encrypted will it still have line feed characters separating the rows? Maybe you need to decrypt first and then process the file (and its rows).